# Dynamically change properties

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to change properties of controls using strings for control name, control AssemblyQualifiedName, Property name and property value

---

**What I have tried:**

```
public void ChangeIt(string ctrlName, string typ,
                     string prop, string value)
{
    Type t = Type.GetType(typ);
    dynamic obj = Convert.ChangeType(App.Current.MainWindow.FindName(ctrlName), t);
    // Now how to
    // obj.Prop=value;
}

ChangeIt("Label1",
        "System.Windows.Controls.Label, PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35",
        "Content", "Hellow World!");
```

Thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Can you give us some context because it doesn't quite seem kosher to me.

Comment: Thank you @Dylan, I am trying to automatically change properties using javascript hosted into WebBrowser and it can't reach WPF Window as it 's not COM visible

Comment: Oh, so ChangeIt() is something you're trying to call from client-side javascript!?

I would take a step back and evaluate another method to accomplish what you are trying to achieve if I were you.  Sorry I couldn't be any more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need the type at all, and you don't need to use dynamic.

```
public void ChangeIt(string ctrlName, string typ, string prop, string value) {
     object obj = App.Current.MainWindow.FindName(ctrlName);
     obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop).SetValue(obj, value);
}
```